# Difference between lookup and join in oracle data integrator

Tags: oracle, join, lookup, oracle-data-integrator

I have created the basic mapping in ODI but i dont understand difference beaten lookup and join.

[image]

Comment: You need to mention what is ODI here and which tool you used to draw this diagram. Also you need to confirm which underlying RDBMS (DB) you are using. This will help others answer your question quickly and precisely. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Lookup provides the solution with **left outer join** by default. Lookup provides the efficiency to retrieve respective columns.

Whereas, join enables you to perform **inner join, left outer join, right outer join and full outer join**.

Comment: If you feel my answer is right, do you mind upvoting?